# When calling an internal subroutine in a parallel Fortran do loop, correct value of iteration variable is not accessible to the subroutine

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran, subroutine

I attempted to write a Fortran program in which an internal subroutine is called inside a parallel do loop. Because the subroutine is not called anywhere except in this loop, and because the iteration variable *i* is global, I didn't see the need to pass it to the subroutine. Here's a simplified outline of the program which highlights the problem:

```
program test
  integer :: i
  i=37

  $omp parallel do private(i)
  do i=1,5
    call do_work
  enddo
  $omp end parallel do

contains
  subroutine do_work
    print *,i
  end subroutine do_work
end program test
```

I'm compiling this program using:

```
gfortran -O0 -fopenmp -o test test.f90
```

I compiled it using gfortran 4.4.6 on a machine with 8 cores, and using gfortran 5.4.0 on another machine with 8 cores, and got:

```
37
37
37
37
37
```

Of course, when compiled without the *-fopenmp* flag, I get the expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So it seems that the pre-loop value of *i* is what do_work is seeing in every thread. Why does the subroutine not see its thread's local value for *i*? And why does passing *i* as an argument to the subroutine resolve the problem? I'm very new to OpenMP, so I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Comment: I think it would help if you named the compiler that you use and the flags you use to compile it.

Comment: Gut feeling is this looks to me like a bug in gfortran, though I would have to delve through the OpenMP spec to be sure and I don't have time at the moment. But that said global variable are BAD, don't use them if at all possible, and if passing i as an argument works go that way, it doesn't just solve your problem, it is better all round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenMP standard does not specify the behaviour of your program.

If you don't pass `i` as an argument, and you want `i` to be private to each thread both within the construct (the source that physically appears between the parallel and end parallel directives) and within the region (the source that is executed in between those directives, then you need to give `i` the OpenMP threadprivate attribute.

Inside the procedure do_work, the variable `i` is referenced by host association, and, inside the procedure, it does not appear lexically within the OpenMP construct - hence inside the procedure it is a variable that is referenced in a region but not in a construct.

Ordinarily 2.15.1.2 of OpenMP 4.5 specifies that reference to `i`, in the procedure, would be shared.

But because `i` is implicitly (because it is a do loop index) and explicitly private within the construct, 2.15.3.3 states that it is unspecified whether references to `i` in the region but not in the construct are to the original (shared) item or the private copy.

When you pass `i` as an argument "by reference", the dummy argument has the same data sharing attribute as the actual argument - i.e. if you pass `i` to the procedure it becomes private.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenMP, when your program enters the do loop, a "[thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)" is created. This is similar to have a subprogram called by your main program, with the exception that the variables of the main program are available to the subprogram.

The parallel region delimited by the loop will however create copies of the private variables, so that every thread has its own version of i. Your subroutine only sees the i of the "supervisor" program, not the local copy of the threads. When using an explicit argument, the subroutine will be told explicitly to use the "thread-local" value for i.

In general (for OpenMP), it is important to consider carefully what variables are local to the parallel region and what variables can remain "global".